# Is it ok to use an iPad (or similar consumer hardware) and electronic charts for GA in Europe?

Tags: visual-flight-rules, easa-regulations, aeronautical-charts, efb

I'm wondering if it is it ok to use a consumer tablet and electronic charts (e.g. within the [AirNav Pro app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-navigation-pro/id301046057?mt=8)) instead of the paper version for recreational VFR single-piston flights?

**Edit**: to clarify, my question is indeed about *official, up-to-date* charts, accessed with consumer hardware (I mention AirNav Pro, but it could well be any pdf reader for that purpose) as opposed to paper medium.

Answer (score 1):

No, these kind of apps (AirNav, VFRNAV etc.) are not meant to replace paper charts. You'll find phrases like this on most of the websites which offer those apps you will find paragraphs like this:

> Please note that this software is not intended to replace a certified navigation device. You should always use official aeronautical documentation when preparing and performing a flight. You should always use certified navigation devices when performing a flight. [Source: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-navigation-pro/id301046057?mt=8 ]

There is certified software like for example Jeppesen Mobile TC available.

Comment: I think the important bit for this question is `You should always use official aeronautical documentation when preparing and performing a flight.` -- so if I loaded (for example) PDFs of a current "official" sectional/IFR chart/approach plate on my iPad, would that be allowed in Europe? (Under the FAA Part 91 rules & [AC 91-78](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgAdvisoryCircular.nsf/list/AC%2091-78/$FILE/AC%2091_78.pdf) this would be OK...)

Comment: You should note that disclaimers like that are in regards to using a portable electronic device + software as a **primary navigation system**. It says nothing about whether or not approach plates displayed on a tablet are legal for use!

Comment: Indeed it doesn't but he asked for software like this and so the answer is no. If you like to know about apps like these from jeppesen or copies of paper charts in pdf form I'm not sure about the legal situation under EASA. I have an 10' tablet with me every flight and there's a bunch of aviation related stuff on it but finally I'm still one who does not go without his own complete and up to date set of aeronautical charts for the whole area. Even if this folder remains on the back seat - I'm 21 and these apps are probably older than my license ;)

Comment: @Falk: egid correctly interpreted my question in the sense that the iPad would be just the medium to access up-to-date, official aeronautical data. I will clarify my question to this effect.

Comment: @voretaq7; at least in Germany, you're required to carry paper charts, whether you use them or not, you must have them along for the ride.

Comment: @roa: do you have a reference for that? could you write an answer?

Comment: @roe As abey already mentioned, could you please quote or link to the regulations that require this and add it as an answer to this question?

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert, @abey; I'll try, this is what I've been taught by the local CFIs. IIRC there's the catch with "official charts" and only the paper ones are official, or something like that. A quick google does indeed say nothing about paper (or any other kind of medium)

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert @abey; Also, Germans are notoriously assuming anything technologically advanced will break. And batteries will run out. That's why you can't legally ride a bike in Germany at night with battery-powered lights, you must have a functioning dynamo along. So my guess is, while probably not strictly forbidden to only have digital charts, they're still gonna bust you on the assumption that your GPS will break...

Comment: @roe You're not making sense. Either it's allowed or not. You're saying that in Germany it is required to carry paper charts but unless you can back that up with official regulations that's just an opinion of yours. I'm pretty sure it's allowed because Jeppesen's iPad apps have been approved by EASA to be used without paper backup charts.

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert; I'm just relaying what I've been taught. The regulations says nothing about the medium, leaving it open to interpretation. And I've been taught, that that interpretation is paper charts or bust. But sure, as long as it's only "my" opinion and not the one of the guy handing out sanctions, you're fine.